# Is there a method to extra audio frequency data from mp4 file using React Native or Node JS?

Tags: node.js, react-native, audio, fft

I'm capturing the audio from the phone microphone using React Native libraries (audio-toolkit).  I'm having some difficulty finding a compatible library that will help me to get the audio frequency data from the audio that is captured.

I'm trying to see if I can implement using my React Native stack.

Comment: what FFT libraries have you tried ?   I would try out several to get a feel ... possibly https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-audio-toolkit ... update your question with your code so we can help

Comment: Hi yes, I am using react-native-audio-toolkit. For now, we are just going to send the audio data for analysis outside of the mobile device. I just need to send the mp4 file. Thanks.